# In pyQt5, why speak(text) run first before self.input text.set Text(text)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried to make text to speech app.
This is my simple code to begin with.
The problem is:
speak(text) is launched first before text.
I want text is launched first or better in the same time.
any suggestions??

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QPushButton
import pyttsx3

text1='Hi my name is Alex, and You?'

def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
       
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('GPT3.5 voice')
        
        # Membuat kotak teks untuk memasukkan teks input
        self.input_text = QTextEdit(self)
        self.input_text.setGeometry(20, 50, 800, 400)

        # Membuat tombol untuk 
        self.translate_button3 = QPushButton('Voice_id', self)
        self.translate_button3.setGeometry(20, 470, 100, 30)
        self.translate_button3.clicked.connect(self.voice_id_2)
        
    def voice_id_2(self):
        self.input_text.setText(text1)
        text2= self.input_text.toPlainText()
        speak(text2)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 840, 900)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want exactly or what's your problem? Add more details please

Comment: As the name should suggest, `runAndWait` is blocking, which means that it prevents the Qt event loop to properly process its queue, including updating the UI. It's not "run before", it's just that you only see the result of the previous command *after* it ends. You need to launch the speech engine in a separate thread.

Comment: Hi  
Oleksandr Spazhev,
I want text is launched first or better in the same time.